# undefined reference to a globally overloaded operator from class method

Tags: c++, oop, global-variables, overloading, linker-errors

My compiler issued the following error :

```
matrix.o: In function `Matrix::modify_cell(unsigned int, unsigned int, int)':
Matrix.cpp:(.text+0x5f): undefined reference to `operator!(Dim)'
Matrix.cpp:(.text+0xa3): undefined reference to `operator!(Dim)'
Matrix.cpp:(.text+0x178): undefined reference to `operator!(Dim)'
Matrix.cpp:(.text+0x1a0): undefined reference to `operator!(Dim)'
matrix.o: In function `List::nula(Dim) const':
Matrix.cpp:(.text._ZNK4List4nulaE3Dim[List::nula(Dim) const]+0x11): undefined reference to `operator!(Dim)'
list1.o:List - auxiliary methods.cpp:(.text+0x3b): more undefined references to `operator!(Dim)' follow
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [app] Error 1
```

Matrix is a class placed in file Matrix.h and Matrix.cpp that inherits from the class List, that in turn is placed in List.h and two other .cpp files. Type Dim (typedef) and operator! for it are declared globally (outside of any class) in aux.h included to List.h and the operator! is defined in aux.cpp. In Matrix.h I include List.h so I do not understand what is the problem. aux.cpp is indeed compiled in my makefile to .o and then joined into single app.

I know that it would be better to place my typedef Dim and its overloaded operator into a class, but it is used both in class List and class Matrix while typedefs are not inherited and I have no idea for any other workaround.

EDIT:

```
// aux.cpp
#include "aux.h"
Dim operator!(Dim dim) { return dim == COL ? ROW : COL; }

// aux.h
#ifndef AUX_H
#define AUX_H

/* (...) */

typedef enum { ROW, COL } Dim;
inline Dim operator!(Dim dim);

#endif
```

Comment: can we see the definition of `operator!(Dim)` ?

Comment: Make sure the declaration and definition of `operator!` are the same.

Comment: @ahenderson yes, that's indeed cruicial. I've just updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared `operator!(Dim)` as inline, so it isn't available unless you also include the definition in the .h. Either move the definition or take out the `inline`.

Comment: thanks, that worked. but I'm kinda confused right now. my sole aim for putting operator! definition in a separate file was that when it was placed in List.h compiler complained for multiple definition of it (as List.h was included multiple times). now it works but it seems to me it should be again the case of multiple defining of operator! (each time header is included). could you explain it to me?

Comment: @infoholic_anonymous, you need header guards to make sure that if a file is included multiple times the contents are only seen once.

Comment: But I do precede every header file with #ifndef #define and end with #endif directives.